# Background image behind isometric tile map

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, isometric

I have been making good progress with my isometric Tile map game using cocos2d.
I have decided to add some artistic background images behind the the Isometric maps.
Unfortunately the images always render on top or in front of the Isometric tile map no matter what the z order of the images is relative to the tile map.

I also have an Orthogonal map in my game with which I have no issues creating background images and controlling the Z order properly.

Just for kicks I tried doing the same with other folks Isometric games and the results were the same.

Is there a special way of adding background images behind Isometric maps?

Comment: Is depth buffering enabled? If so, use vertexZ instead of zOrder to control draw order.

Comment: Thanks Steffen I have depthFormat: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES i my appDelegate but no luck. even using another layer bellow the aprrent layer of the tile map won't work. tried to use vertexz but then nothing is rendered

Comment: I managed to get the image properly behind the tile map by changing depthFormat: to 0 in appDelegate but now the player and game objects don't render properly any more when in contact with each other